# CSSearchableItemAttributeSet: can't define third line content

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, corespotlight

So, is there a table anywhere explaining how each itemContentType will be rendered on the final search?

For now I only got:

`kUTTypeMovie` will render the `duration` on the third line.

`kUTTypeMessage` will render the `contentCreationDate` on the top right corner

I wanted to get a custom text on the third line, is it possible?

If not, how to only draw a year there, like this: 
[image]

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution? I use `kUTTypeMovie` and I need to show movie release date and duration on the third line. But on iOS11, apple show   (2018 — 1:35:22), where 2018 is a year when this SearchableItem was added, and `contentCreationDate` is ignored(

Comment: Didn't found it, sorry :/ Apple's documentation on this is terrible

Comment: Where did you find out to use kUTTypeMovie and kUTTypeMessage? Can't find it in the docs...